# How to hide Liferay 5.2.3 Message Board restricted category?

Tags: liferay

I want to hide the restricted category instead of red and not clickable option.
I think there is no GUI option in Liferay 5.2.3 to hide restricted category. Can anyone suggest me what I can change in the code to achieve this?

Comment: I found the page view.jsp inside message board portlet and " <liferay-ui:search-iterator searchContainer="<%= searchContainer %>" />" is used to display the categories. Anyone can suggest me from where this is calling the relevant categories name by using the mentioned code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found one solution by some hit and trail with the help of this link http://issues.liferay.com/browse/LPS-8344.

Go to  tomcat-6.0.18\webapps\ROOT\html\portlet\message_boards\view.jsp

and change following lines

```java
if (restricted) {
    row.addText(StringPool.BLANK);
}
```

to

```java
if (restricted) {
    continue;
}
```

I hope if someone has better solution then this will post here. :)